# Consume CellInfoWcdma classes in android API level 17

Tags: android, upgrade, telephonymanager, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm looking to neighbor cell rssi signal using TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() which returns a list of CellInfo (abstract class extended for different cell tower types, gsm, lte, cdma ecc.) objects with all the information that I need.

My apps has been built using android API level 17 and works fine.

When I run the application on a new phone just upgraded to Android 4.3 (API level 18), the call getAllCellInfo() returns a list of CellInfoWcdma (a new class added in API level 18).

For several reason I can't upgrade my sdk.

How can I get the cell id and rssi from this kind of objects without upgrading my sdk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection:

```
private static class CellIdentityWcdma {
    private static Class<?> mCls;
    private static Method mGetCid;
    private static Method mGetLac;
    private static Method mGetMcc;
    private static Method mGetMnc;
    private static Method mGetPsc;
    static {
        try {
            mCls = Class.forName("android.telephony.CellIdentityWcdma");
            mGetCid = mCls.getMethod("getCid");
            mGetLac = mCls.getMethod("getLac");
            mGetMcc = mCls.getMethod("getMcc");
            mGetMnc = mCls.getMethod("getMnc");
            mGetPsc = mCls.getMethod("getPsc");
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        }
    }
    private final Object mObj;
    public CellIdentityWcdma(final Object obj) {
        mObj = obj;
    }
    public int getCid() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return ((Integer)mGetCid.invoke(mObj)).intValue();
    }
    public int getLac() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return ((Integer)mGetLac.invoke(mObj)).intValue();
    }
    public int getMcc() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return ((Integer)mGetMcc.invoke(mObj)).intValue();
    }
    public int getMnc() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return ((Integer)mGetMnc.invoke(mObj)).intValue();
    }
    public int getPsc() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return ((Integer)mGetPsc.invoke(mObj)).intValue();
    }
}

private static class CellSignalStrengthWcdma {
    private static Class<?> mCls;
    private static Method mGetAsuLevel;
    static {
        try {
            mCls = Class.forName("android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthWcdma");
            mGetAsuLevel = mCls.getMethod("getAsuLevel");
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        }
    }
    private final Object mObj;
    public CellSignalStrengthWcdma(final Object obj) {
        mObj = obj;
    }
    public int getAsuLevel() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return ((Integer)mGetAsuLevel.invoke(mObj)).intValue();
    }
}

private static class CellInfoWcdma {
    private static Class<?> mCls;
    private static Method mGetCellIdentity;
    private static Method mGetCellSignalStrength;
    static {
        try {
            mCls = Class.forName("android.telephony.CellInfoWcdma");
            mGetCellIdentity = mCls.getMethod("getCellIdentity");
            mGetCellSignalStrength = mCls.getMethod("getCellSignalStrength");
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
        }
    }
    private final Object mObj;
    public CellInfoWcdma(final Object obj) {
        mObj = obj;
    }
    public static boolean isInstance(final Object obj) {
        return null != mCls && mCls.isInstance(obj);
    }
    public CellIdentityWcdma getCellIdentity()
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return new CellIdentityWcdma(mGetCellIdentity.invoke(mObj));
    }
    public CellSignalStrengthWcdma getCellSignalStrength()
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        return new CellSignalStrengthWcdma(mGetCellSignalStrength.invoke(mObj));
    }
}

private static void useCellInfo(final CellInfo cellInfo) {
    if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
        useGsm((CellInfoGsm)cellInfo);
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoLte) {
        useLte((CellInfoLte)cellInfo);
    } else if (cellInfo instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
        useCdma((CellInfoCdma)cellInfo);
    } else if (CellInfoWcdma.isInstance(cellInfo)) {
        useWcdma(new CellInfoWcdma(cellInfo));
    }
}
```